# Unable to login to the Jenkins application installed on my local machine

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I want to configured Jenkins with selenium webdriver on my local machine. I have downloaded the jenkins.war file and successfully ran from CMD. But now it is asking me for username and password. Which username and password I need to provide?[image]

Comment: What version jenkins war you have downloaded ?

Comment: The latest one. 2.66 from the website https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins is initially configured to be secure on first launch. During the initial run of Jenkins a security token is generated and printed in the console log.

You can use admin as username and the token as a password, if you skipped the user-creation.

Go through the documents for more detail.

[Jenkins Installation Document](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/getting-started/installing/)